# Similarity of tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

At the moment, I try to work myself into tensors, and, especially, similarity of tensors, following the definition of matrix similarity:

Two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are called **similar** if there exists an invertible $n$-by-$n$ matrix $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP$.

In my situation, for example, I have a symmetric tensor $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{10 \times 10 \times 10}$ and a orthogonal matrix $U \in \mathbb{R}^{10 \times 10}$ and I'm looking at the following (with a $1$-mode product $\times_1$):

$$
U^{-1} \mathcal{X} U = U^T \mathcal{X} U = (\mathcal{X}^T U)^T U = (\mathcal{X} U)^T U = (\mathcal{X} \times_1 U)^T \times_1 U.
$$

Does this hold? Especially, I'm wondering about equality $2$ (I'm using a rule from linear algebra) and $3$ (should hold due to the symmetry of $\mathcal{X}$).

I'm very thankful for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{X}^T$ when $\mathcal{X}$ is a tensor? And are the products in $U^{-1}\mathcal{X}U$ meant to be contractions on the last and first indices?

Comment: @VladimirLysikov By $\mathcal{X}^T$ I mean the full transposition which should be equal to $\mathcal{X}$ by definition as $\mathcal{X}$ is symmetric.
What do you mean by contractions on the last and first indices? I'm referring to the definition of the $n$-mode product, e.g. by Bader and Kolda.

Comment: I still don't understand. If a tensor has $3$ indices, then we can permute them in any way, so there is no one notion of transposition, instead you have an action of the symmetric group $S_3$ on indices. And if the tensor $\mathcal{X}$ is symmetric, then $\mathcal{X}^\sigma = \mathcal{X}$ for all permutations $\sigma$. Still, $\mathcal{X}U$ is not symmetric, so $(\mathcal{X}U)^T$ is not defined — there are in general 5 different transposed tensors.

Comment: Okay I see your point. I think in my case it would not really matter, but in general does it mean that the matrix formula $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ just cannot be defined for tensors?

Comment: Yes — transposition for tensors is not defined, you need to specify the permutation of indices to apply.